# fileUpload in GAS with the same name and extension

Tags: google-apps-script

I hope that you can help me, I have a issue.
I need a form in GAS that can upload a file to google drive with the original name. but I can´t make work. I don't know that is wrong, but the file not have extention and the name is Undefined..
this is my simple code;
thanks for all.

```
function doGet(p) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel().setId('flow');

  var gridfile = app.createGrid(5,3);
  var flabel0 = app.createLabel('Upload the file');
  var flabel1 = app.createLabel('Select file: ');

  var thefile = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile').setId('thefile');

  var handlerxx = app.createServerHandler('uploadfile').addCallbackElement(flow); 
 thefile.addChangeHandler(handlerxx);

    gridfile.setWidget(0, 0, flabel0)
    .setWidget(2, 0, flabel1)
    .setWidget(2, 1, thefile);

  flow.add(gridfile);

  app.add(flow);  
    return app; 
}

function uploadfile(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  

  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.thefile,"application/zip",e.parameter.thefile);
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);

  app.getElementById('flow').add(app.createLabel('File Uploaded successfully'));
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only upload a file in a `doGet / doPost` form structure.

Instead of explaining in details I thought it would be easier to show a working example (honestly it's also simpler ...)

so there it is, note that I had to add a submit button to trigger the form submission.

By the way I added a `'loading'` label shown by a client handler because otherwise nothing happens during upload and users can be worrying !!

I commented out the line about zip type and fileName since the uploaded file will keep the name and type automatically.

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var form = app.createFormPanel();
  var flow = app.createFlowPanel().setId('flow');
  form.add(flow);
  var gridfile = app.createGrid(5,3);
  var flabel1 = app.createLabel('Select file: ');
  var lab = app.createLabel('LOADING').setStyleAttributes({'color':'red'}).setVisible(false).setId('lab');
var cliHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(lab).setVisible(true);  
  var thefile = app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile').setId('thefile');
  var button = app.createSubmitButton('Upload the file').addClickHandler(cliHandler);
  gridfile.setWidget(2, 0, flabel1)
  .setWidget(2, 1, thefile)
  .setWidget(2, 2, button);
  flow.add(gridfile).add(lab);

  app.add(form);  
  return app; 
}

function doPost(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();  
  Logger.log('doPost');
//  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.thefile,"application/zip",e.parameter.thefile);
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(e.parameter.thefile);
  app.getElementById('lab').setVisible(false);
  app.add(app.createLabel('File Uploaded successfully'));
  return app;
}
```

Comment: thanks for all, this working. My app doesn't use doPost(), but I'll try to adapt.